# IsSectionDefined returning outputting value

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I am attempting to see whether a section is defined in a view and use that if so.

I am doing:

```
@IsSectionDefined("title") ? RenderSection("title",true) : <title>@Viewbag.Title</title>
```

However, this is giving back the value, for example printing "True ?" in my view

I can do it like:

```
@if(IsSectionDefined("title"))
{
   RenderSection("title",true)
}
else
{
   <title>@ViewBag.Title</title>
}
```

However, I think the above is ugly...and would like to do it the first way...

Anyone know how I can use the first method but not print the value of `IsSectionDefined`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your second approach with the `if` is perfectly fine, so you should stick to it.

However if you want to use the conditional operator you have to make some adjustments. 
The main problem is that the `RenderSection` returns a `HelperResult` so the other part of your conditional has to return also a `HelperResult`.

The easiest way to solve this to move your view logic into a Razor helper function which will return a `HelperResult` what you can use in the conditional operator:

```
@helper DisplayTitle()
{
    <title>@ViewBag.Title</title>
}

@(IsSectionDefined("title") ? RenderSection("title",true) : DisplayTitle())
```